# How does one enter a Python virtualenv when executing a bashscript?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

If one defines which version of python to use in a bash script, it would be

```
export PYTHON = "/path/python/python-3.5.1/bin/python"
```

But for Python virtualenv's, one executes these commands in the command line

```
cd /path/pathto/virtualenv
source activate
cd another_directory
```

How does one "enter" a Python virtualenv in a bash script? What is the standard approach here?

Comment: Use python script for entering python virtualenv. Begin the file with `#! /usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @IporSircer How would you use the python script for entering the virtualenv?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have to distinguish two cases here:

1. You want to use/call python (or python-based tools) in your bash script, but python or those tools should be taken from and run in a virtualenv
2. You want a script that, amongst other things, lets the shell from which you call it enter the virtualenv, so that you can interactively call python (or python-based tools) inside the virtualenv

## Case 1: Using a virtualenv inside a script

> How does one "enter" a Python virtualenv in a bash script?

Just like on the interactive bash command line:

```sh
source /path/to/the/virtual_env/bin/activate
```

> What is the standard approach here?

The standard approach is **not** to *enter* the virtualenv in a bash script. Instead, call python and/or the python-based commands you want to use by their full path. To make this easier and less repetitive, you can use aliases and variables.

## Case 2: Activating a virtualenv in an interactive bash session by calling a script

There already is such a script. It's called `activate` and it's located in the `bin` directory of the virtualenv. You have to `source` it rather than calling it like a normal command. Only then will it run in the same session instead of in a subshell, and thus only then can it make modifications to the session that won't be lost due to the subshell terminating at the end of the script.

So just do:

```sh
source /path/to/the/virtual_env/bin/activate
```

in your interactive shell session.

But what if you want to do more than the `activate` script does? You can put

```sh
source /path/to/the/virtual_env/bin/activate
```

into a shell script. **But**, due to the reason mentioned above, it won't have much effect when you call your script normally. Instead, `source` your script to use it from an interactive session.

Thus:

Content of `my_activate.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Do something
# ...

# then
source /path/to/the/virtual_env/bin/activate

# Do more stuff
# ...
```

and in your interactive session

```sh
source my_activate.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using virtualenvwrapper.  It provides some useful tools for managing your virtual environments.

```
pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
```

When you create the virtual environment, you specify which version of python should be used in the environment.

```
mkvirtualenv  -p /usr/local/bin/python2.6  myproject.2.6
mkvirtualenv  -p /usr/local/bin/python3.3  myproject.3.3
```

Then, "enter" the environment with the workon command.

```
workon myproject.2.6
```

Answer (score -3):

Here are few steps to follow, one thing you can do is

```
export PYTHON = "/path/pathto/virtualenv/python"
```

Use this path in bashrc to use. Or you can do something like:-

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Go to end and set

```
alias python=/path/pathto/virtualenv/python
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: "Use this path in bashrc to use." I'm not following. How do I "activate" the virtualenv?

Comment: No need to activate virtualenv just use this path "/path/pathto/virtualenv/python" like i have "/home/rakeshkumar/trading/venv/bin/python". I followed alias method and working fine for me.

Comment: As my normal python have 2.7, after using alias to virtualenv, python command using 3.5

Comment: Can you explain why you both `EXPORT` python and define it via `alias python=path`? Perhaps this is a n00b question, but wouldn't you just need the former?

Comment: ok, I am not using `EXPORT` way, i am using `alis python=path` way. I wrote `EXPORT` in answer, thought you want to use with `EXPORT`.

Comment: My Preferred way is `alias python=path`