# systemd start a script that activate virtual env not take effect

Tags: python, systemd, python-venv

I was trying to systemd a flask app. I tried to write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/app
source venv/bin/activate
python start.py
```

and just ExecStart this script in the .service file. But this doesn't quite work as starting the service errors with

> python: command not found

I actually ran into quite a few issues, but eventually resolved with service file:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/app
ExecStart=/path/to/app/venv/bin/python start.py
```

Without `WorkingDirectory`, the file paths do not seem to work as the static file can't even be found.

So my question is actually why doesn't script above in the beginning work? The `cd` took effect, but the venv activate didn't?

Comment: I can't immediately see any reason why the Bash script shouldn't work. As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40896676/), sourcing the activate script for a virtual environment from a Bash script should just work. Have you tried running (and debugging) the script you wrote manually (i.e., without systemd)?

Comment: yea, the script works if you simply run the cmd manually...